# Stop asking for sudo on reading or writing files on /mnt/My_partition

Tags: permissions, sudo

I have a partition on my SSD that I store files on other than the partition of my system.
I use this partition very often, but whenever I copy a file from my system to that partition, it asks me for the sudo password, and I want to remove that.

How do I stop it from asking me the sudo password for reading and writing for this partition?

For example:

```
sam@sam:~/Documents$ mv test.txt /mnt/Data
mv: cannot create regular file '/mnt/Data/test.txt': Permission denied
```

- **/Data**/ :-  the partition.

another example:

```
sam@sam:/mnt/Data$ touch something.txt
touch: cannot touch 'something.txt': Permission denied
```

If I wanted to perform those actions, I'll have to write sudo with the password, but that's not what I want.

Comment: What user owns the partition?

Comment: Just one note that might be useful, the /mnt/Data partition is ext4

Comment: @David, I believe the root,? it's only me on that laptop, my username is sam

Comment: @David drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 32768 Jan  1  1970 Data/

Comment: You just answered your own question. It works the way it should, Sam has no right to write to the partition.

Comment: Thanks for help :D

Comment: No really, I want it to stop asking for that password, so how do I give myself "sam" the permissions?

Comment: Change the owner of the partition to your user (sam), then you won't need sudo.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)   *Details provided in subsequent question*

Answer (score 2):

Your `/mnt/Data` partition is owned by root, so your user "sam" has no permissions to write to it.

Change the ownership of the partition (and everything on it, recursively) to user "sam":

```
sudo chown -R sam:sam /mnt/Data
```

Comment: OK, 


`chown: changing ownership of '/mnt/Data/Downloads': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/mnt/Data': Operation not permitted`
... and for every file in the partition

Comment: Use `sudo chown -R sam:sam /mnt/Data`.